# Hold/Freeze Transformation Orientation

Tags: transform-orientation

I was wondering if there is a way of briefly locking a transformation orientation (TO)

Most often when editing shapes, I find myself using the normal mode for TO when I want to move something along the direction of an edge or plane. But because the TO depends on the selection, what I have to do is:

1. Select edge/plane that I need for my TO.
2. Create a custom TO from the current one.
3. Select the thing I actually want to move/scale/rotate and my custom TO.
4. Perform the action.
5. Remove the custom TO.

So each time I do this I create a custom TO that I most likely will delete shortly afterwards. Is there a way of "holding" or "freezing" the TO? Something like a toggle button or shortcut? This way I could stay in normal mode all the time and just need to:

1. Select my edge|plane to get my desired TO & hit the TO-freeze button.
2. Select my action target and perform the action.